# facing an error while running flask when I add login_manager to my app

Tags: python, cs50, flask-login

I'm trying to implement a flask project for CS50 final project and I have problem with login and sessions.

When I try to add this:
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user

I face with this problem:
final/ $ flask run
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 219, in locate_app
**import**(module_name)
File "/workspaces/96314997/final/app.py", line 9, in 
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask_login/**init**.py", line 12, in 
final/ $     from .login_manager import LoginManager
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask_login/login_manager.py", line 33, in 
from .utils import _create_identifier
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 14, in 
from werkzeug.urls import url_decode
ImportError: cannot import name 'url_decode' from 'werkzeug.urls' (/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/werkzeug/urls.py)

When I delete the library part, the flask runs but when I add it the error appears.

these are my libraries:

```py
from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_session import Session
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
from datetime import datetime
import os
import smtplib
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
```